# determine whether differential equation is exact or not and solve it

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find out whether the following equation is exact or not:

\begin{equation}
(2k \sin(k + l) + \cos(k + l))dk + \cos(k + l)dl = 0
\end{equation}

I learned from my math book that you can check if the equation is exact by finding if $\Psi_{kl}$ = $\Psi_{lk}$

so going back to my equation I have:

\begin{equation}
(2k \sin(k + l) + \cos(k + l)) \neq \cos(k + l)
\end{equation}

since the two terms are not equal the differential equation is not exact right?

Also how would I solve this differential equation? I have no idea how to do it.

Moreover, I know that the variables k and l are related and l is dependent and k independent and also that it has an integrating factor g(k).

Comment: Are you sure you wrote it down correctly? 
It seems a little dubious that there appears the term $dkdl$ in your second equation.

Comment: @Creo yes I copied it correctly

Comment: But then it isn't a system of differential equations. Hence it's neither exact nor can you solve it. Out of curiousity: Where did you get it from?

Comment: @Creo Its a last year practice exam question. I know it should have some answer, but I noticed that I actually added accidentally one extra bracket, can you please check it now?

Comment: You should compare partial derivatives of the coefficients, not the coefficients themselves. Please read carefully the definition of the exact differential equation, at least here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation

Comment: @YuriyS So i need to compare $$\partial/\partial k [2ksin(k+l)+cos(k+l)] \neq \partial / \partial l [cos(k+l)]$$ ?

Comment: @1muflon1, the other way around... The exact equation is in the form $$dU(x,y)=\partial_x U(x,y) dx+\partial_y U(x,y) dy=0$$ So you need to use the fact that $$\partial_{xy} U(x,y)=\partial_{yx} U(x,y)$$

Comment: It doesn't seem like your equation is exact...

Comment: @YuriyS okay and how could I find the integrating factor and solve it?

Comment: @1muflon1, searching for integrating factors is more of an art than exact science... I don't know. Are you sure you've got the equation right?

Comment: @YuriyS Yes, originally I had there mistake but now its fixed